Renaming to Polkadot-SDK
As the repository for substrate is now archived, would it be possible to rename this Stack Exchange to also be called "Polkadot SDK StackExchange"?
This site can be used to ask questions about all things related to developing on top of the Polkadot tech stack.
I think the most future-proof word to describe this is "Polkadot SDK". It encompasses Polkadot Parachains, Polakdot-based Solochains (old school substrate), client libraries (PJS, PAPI), and more.
I am not sure if the URL can be saved/changed in a meaningful way.

+1 for Polkadot-SDK.

polkadot based urls redirect here. i am not sure we really gain much by this. SEO probably already picks up "polkadot" from the shared name

I can imagine that if you search anything Polkadot related you land here, and since Polkadot is already in the title, it is not all that bad. Just that "Substrate" is a bit backwards.
What is the process of renaming? It would help evaluate if this is worth the while or not.

@kianenigma maybe your request would be that substrate.stackexchange.com would forward to polkadot.stackexchange.com instead of the reverse? Would need an admin of the stackexchange platform to do this. Not sure if this is the kind of thing they entertain or not. I think they kind of already gave us special treatment with the two urls :P

How about renaming it to "Polkadot & Substrate" or just "Polkadot"?
